# When will Visual Studio Code be compatible with MacOS Catalina 10.15.x

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, system-requirements

The Visual Studio Code Requirements page:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements

doesn't even list the current MacOS 10.14.x (Mojave) support. When will 10.15.x (Catalina) be supported?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "be compatible" ? 
It worked in Mojave and works in Catalina now, without any issues. As for requirements page I think oldest OS mentioned, not latest. i.e. Minimal requirements

Comment: The GitHub issue tracking the actual resolution of this matter is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74782

Answer (score 6):

VS Code does not open directly on Catalina due to notorization requirements. You can bypass this simply by going to System Preferences -> Security and click 'open anyway'.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studo Code runs on MacOs Catalina. The link that you have referenced refers to platforms that VS Code has been *tested* on. It may take a while for Microsoft to update the platforms to include Catalina, but in general you will not experience problems when running VS Code on Catalina.

If you are interested in issues that have been opened against VS Code running on Catalina, you can use this link: [VS Code Catalina Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20catalina)

Answer (score 1):

VSCode runs on Catalina, but it has some subscription issues. To bypass it, you need to place the VsCode under the `Applications` folder and then `right-click on the VsCode icon and click open`.This helps to bypass the blocker.

Answer (score 0):

The link is showing "OS X Yosemite" as the tested macOS platform.
If you would look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac, you could see a section regarding Mojave called "Mojave privacy protections".
Furthermore, I can say that it works both under Mojave and Catalina (just updated yesterday) as I'm using VS Code on Mac at work.